# What "appear to be " means in the given sentence

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, sentence, subcontinental-english

Today, while reading a newspaper I came across a sentence that has been baffling me since:

> The woman, who identified herself as Bhavna and **appeared to be in her 20s, ....**

What does **appeared to be in her 20s** mean in the above sentence?**

Comment: You can upvote a question and answer when you have more than 15 reputation points. Now, please read the guidelines in our Help Center carefully. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**.

Answer (score 3):

It means the woman looked like she was between the ages of 20 and 30. As @jera notes, it doesn't disclose her true age.

Comment: but she hasn't confirmed the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

From her appearance, it could be guessed, though not correctly but presumably, that the woman was in the age bracket of 20–30 years.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!!!!!.......one question I am naive to stack exchange I would like to up vote answer by you and others but when I am up voting, it shows something in a red background that I am not getting

Comment: It seems that you will have to earn a qualifying reputation score and get badges to up vote an answer.
Please check the link: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Comment: @DeepanshucAnand You should still be able to accept one of the answers to your own question as correct even if you don't have enough rep to up-vote them.

Comment: I am up voting but still it's showing the same flag